# How do you clear the Response buffer in ColdFusion?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm looking for something like `Response.Clear()`.

Comment: GetPageContext().getCFOutput().clear() and <cfcontent reset=true /> are both correct.

Comment: If only SO would let me accept two answers...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This will clear the response body and prevent the output of buffered content -

```
<cfset GetPageContext().getCFOutput().clear()>
```

Comment: Be careful that using this may make your code non-portable from Adobe Coldfusion to Railo or OpenBluedragon.

Comment: Agree, I didn't know about cfcontent.  Edward's answer is better and will be compatible with other CF Engines.

Answer (score 29):

You can reset the output buffer using the [cfcontent](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-c/cfcontent.html) tag with the reset argument:

```
<cfcontent reset="true">
```

Comment: This is the same functionality as `<cfset GetPageContext().getCFOutput().clear()>` but it is documented, supported, and as Edward points out in his comment on jfrobishow's answer, portable between CFML engines. This is the way to go.

Comment: There are issues with this one, too, though.  CFHTMLHEAD, CFFORM javascript, and a few other things are stored in a different output buffer and are appended at the end of the request.  CFCONTENT RESET won't clear the markup on this other buffer, so you end up still getting it output.

Answer (score 0):

The two existing answers (`<cfset GetPageContext().getCFOutput().clear()>` and `<cfcontent reset="true">`) will reset the main content buffer, but those commands will not reset the header buffers (i.e. content that ColdFusion automatically inserts into the `<head>` element such as `<script>` tags when using `<cfchart>`).

To reset everything, you can use either of the following approaches:

```
<cfcontent reset="true" resethead="true">
```

or

```
<cfset getPageContext().getCFOutput().clearAll()>
<cfset getPageContext().getCFOutput().clearHeaderBuffers()>
```

These approaches are not documented (so possible to change in future version -- though unlikely) and these approaches are unlikely to be portable to other CFML engines, but I have not found any documented approach for clearing the header buffers.

Related answer: [Is there a way to prevent cfchart from forcing js into response content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46731606/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-cfchart-from-forcing-js-into-response-content/59756665#59756665)